# Is it possible to code Reason React on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, reason, reason-react

I'm in the unfortunate situation for the next few months of having to use a Windows 8.1 machine on web development.

I'm currently interested in ReasonML and I'm using Visual Studio code. Reason React is what I'm interested in to be exact. It seems that Reason doesn't like Windows that much. There is a WSL workaround for windows 10
( https://github.com/reasonml/reasonml.github.io/issues/195 )
but as far as I know that's not doable on Windows 8.1

Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try intellij idea (I'm the author of the [reason plugin](https://github.com/reasonml-editor/reasonml-idea-plugin)).

You won't get all the features you have with VSCode, it's still a work in progress, but it works natively on windows : no WSL, no cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for creating a StackOverflow profile just to answer this :D I saw brilliant presentations of Reason in React Finland last week. A lot of my fellow devs got very interested in it.